# Material-UI animations rendering extremely slow in Chrome Extension popup

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-ui

I am building a chrome extension using React and Material-UI for the popup. I used create-react-app to set everything up. The rendering of Material UI component animations (switch toggle, select highlighting on mouse over, button ripple, etc) is extremely slow. OnClick methods fire just fine but the animations have issues.

The animation rendering is very slow in my chrome extension popup. As elements get farther down in the DOM the animations get progressively slower.

I tried a bunch of different things to try and figure out what was causing the issue. I ended up removing background from my manifest.json and all of a sudden the animations were rendering just fine. I thought that maybe something in my code was causing the issue. So I made an empty background.js file and added it to my manifest and the rendering was slow again.

With background in manifest.json
[image: Slow Animation Material UI]

Without background in manifest.json
[image: Fanst Animation]

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.1.0",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "browser_action": {
       
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Test"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

test.js

```
import React from "react";
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';

export default function Test(props){
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch/>
            <Switch/>
            <Switch/>
            <Switch/>
            <Switch/>
            <Switch/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Test from "./test";

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Note: I've only seen this error happen on Mac. I've tried on Linux and Windows but haven't seen the same issue. And it only sometimes happens on Mac. I haven't tested it on Linux and Windows nearly as long as I have on Mac (because I develop on Mac).

Specs

Material-UI - v4.11.0

React - 16.12

Browser - Google Chrome  Version 86.0.4240.111

Machine - 2015 Macbook Pro Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: https://crbug.com/971701

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the link! At least now I know why it's happening.